# How to represent enums in graphql schema if they come from a data source?

Tags: rest, graphql, aws-appsync

I have a REST api I'm hitting. One of the paths is /types/ that returns just a json array of strings, each string the name of a type. This type is used elsewhere in the schema as the type enum value of other objects. How do I represent this in the graphql schema? I'm using aws AppSync, but I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting your schema up as follows:

```
enum Types {
  a,
  b,
  c
}

type Query {
  listTypes: [Types]
}
```

Comment: You won't know what a, b, c, etc. is because they come from the api. They're dynamic, not static.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how you are expecting this to work?